# Jasmine failing with Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to get a project to work properly with Jasmine.  I am using the project that I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/uzikilon/Todos/tree/master/test/).  I added another spec file, PatientSpec.js:

```
describe('Patient :: Create', function() {
  it("Must note be null", function() {
    require(['models/Patient'], function(Patient) {
      var patient1 = new Patient();
      expect(patient).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

You see that my var is named `patient1` and I am running the expectation on the variable name `patient`.  When I look at my index.html, all of my tests are passing, and this is obviously not defined.  I pull up my console and I here is my error:

[image]

What would cause this error?  Why does it fail silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails silently cause the error happens in the callback of your `require` call not in your test. So when the error is thrown **after** your test has finished. You have to run your test inside of the callback:

```
require(['models/Patient'], function(Patient) {
  describe('Patient :: Create', function() {
    it("Must note be null", function() {
      var patient1 = new Patient();
      expect(patient).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

Take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423156/getting-requirejs-to-work-with-jasmine) do understand how to test requireJs modules

Comment: Beautiful, but when I do that then my tests don't show up on my Jasmine result page.  How do I get the test describe block to show up and catch the errors on the page?

Comment: Updated my post with a link to description.