# How do I get Jasmine to always show the spec list?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

If my Jasmine test has failures, it only shows those by default. I have to click "Spec List" to see all of the tests that were run.

Can I somehow get it to always show the spec list by default?

Answer (score 1):

I am using jasmine 2.1.3 with require.js as outlined in this stackoverflow question: 
[Getting requirejs to work with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423156/getting-requirejs-to-work-with-jasmine)
and this was bugging me too.

I am also using jquery so I added an event trigger after the .execute() like so:

```
require(specs, function (spec) {
        jasmineEnv.execute();
        $('.spec-list-menu').click();
      });
```

I couldn't find any configuration for setting the default, but you can see in the jasmine-html.js file:

```
    find('.failures-menu').onclick = function() {
      setMenuModeTo('failure-list');
    };
    find('.spec-list-menu').onclick = function() {
      setMenuModeTo('spec-list');
    };

    setMenuModeTo('failure-list');
```

if you changed it to:

```
    find('.failures-menu').onclick = function() {
      setMenuModeTo('failure-list');
    };
    find('.spec-list-menu').onclick = function() {
      setMenuModeTo('spec-list');
    };

    setMenuModeTo('spec-list');
```

It will also set the default.

I don't really like editing libraries like that since I usually forget what I have changed when I update the library.

That was the reason I went with the jquery route.