# How we write basic unit test in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular

I have following angular documentation in official site. but in documentation testing part is outdated and not working with the current angular 2 beta versions. I need to write a basic test for check the if condition are working correctly. how can i do that using jasmine in angular 2.

Comment: Can you please post what you tried and where you failed? Any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now angular have good documentation on angular 2 unit test and end to end testing using jasmine and karma. it have explain it using example and very easy to understand and follow.

Reference : [angular 2 test](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#atu-intro)

Answer (score 9):

**Setup jasmine to run typescript unit tests with angular2 (beta.7):**

1. Setup an Angular-Project
   (see description 5 Min Quickstart 
   https://angular.io/guide/quickstart )

   Rootdir is myproject
2. install jasmine with mpm

   ```
   npm install jasmine-core --save-dev --save-exact
   ```
3. Install live-server
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server
4. Get syntax/intellisense support:
   in myproject/typings make a new file jasmine.d.ts

   ```
   /// <reference path="jasmine\jasmine.d.ts" />
   ```

   Get the jasmine.d.ts from
   https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts

   and save it in myproject\typings\jasmine as file jasmine.d.ts
5. Save unit-test.html in myproject

   ```
   <html>
    <head>
      <title>Angular2: Jasmine Tests</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
      <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
      <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
      <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <!-- #1. add the system.js library -->
     <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
     <script>
          // #2. Configure SystemJS to use the .js extension
          //     for imports from the app folder
       System.config({
       packages: {
       'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
       }
     });
          // #3. Import the spec file explicitly
      System.import('app/app.spec')
          // #4. wait for all imports to load ...
          //     then re-execute `window.onload` which
          //     triggers the Jasmine test-runner start
          //     or explain what went wrong
     .then(window.onload)
     .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
      </body>
      </html>
   ```

   **.then (window.onload)** is important to start testexecution.

   see here [Wait for a module to be loaded to execute the tests it contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608358/wait-for-a-module-to-be-loaded-to-execute-the-tests-it-contains/35624225#35624225)
6. Create new file app.spec.ts in dir myproject\app

   ```
   import {AppComponent} from './app.component';


   // Jasmin Test  App title property
   describe('AppComponent', () => {
       var app: AppComponent = null

       beforeEach(() => {
       app = new AppComponent();
       app.title = "App in Test";
       });

      it('should have an title property', () => {

         expect(app.title).toBeDefined();
      });

      it('should have the title App in Test', () => {

         expect(app.title).toBe("App in Test");
      })
   });


   // Jasmin Test without Angular
   describe("A suite", function() {
       it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
           expect(true).toBe(true);
       });
   });
   ```
7. From the cmdline start

   ```
   live-server --open=unit-test.html
   ```

This is my working setup for running Unit-Tests with Jasmine written in typescript with Angular 2.

If you have any errors please post what you tried and where you failed like Günther proposed in his comment.

Comment: i will try this and if it work i will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this to be a good guide for angular testing](http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2016/01/testing-angular-2-with-karma-and-jasmine/)

It is missing the following command though:

```
typings install jasmine --save-dev --ambient
```